# Swift 3.0 save a score with SpriteKit

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I am trying to save a "highScore" integer that persists after the app is closed using SpriteKit.

That's it. Just one single integer on one single screen that I will eventually set with my game whether or not the new score is higher than the saved score.

I understand that there are a lot of options already on stackoverflow for this, however they are all for versions of Swift less than 3.0. They use a bunch of methods and built-in functionality that I don't understand as a beginner. After trying to convert all of these options to Swift 3.0 and failing, I am hoping someone can show me some sample code how to do this.

I will be happy to answer any further questions.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `UserDefaults` class for that purpose.

If you have any sort of `GameManager` singleton, you can define a computed variable which saves and reads from `UserDefaults`:

```
var highScore: Int {
    get {
        return UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "highScore")
    }
    set {
        UserDefaults.standard.set(newValue, forKey: "highScore")
    }
}
```

Comment: There is an `integer(forKey:` and appropriate setter method which works non-optional.

Comment: Also, no need to synchronize every time. UserDefaults will do that automatically before closing the app and at different intervals. Forcing synchronize might affect performance if the variable is read set a lot, once per frame, for example.

Comment: @EmilioPelaez Yes, it makes sense, but perhaps not in this case. Why would you ever set highScore once per frame?

Comment: @alexburtnik imagine an endless runner, every frame you check if the user has broken the current high score, if he has, you set a new one. You could set it at the end of the game, of course, but this way the high score gets saved even if the game crashes or is closed mid-game.