# saving coins variable in swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, nsuserdefaults

i am kinda new to swift  and i need help with saving an int variable that holds the user's coins that they collect and saving it even after the app closes , so here is what i did , i have two scenes one represents startMenu which has the a struct that has the coins variable ( so i can easily control it from another scene )  , and the other scene which is GameScene , and in GameScene every time the user interacts with a coin node , it adds 1 to the coins variable in StarMenu Scene

here in my struct in StartMenu

```
struct Variables {

    static var CoinsCollected = 0


}
```

and here is what i did to make it be saved

```
    let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
    defaults.set(Variables.CoinsCollected, forKey: "CoinsCollected")
    defaults.synchronize()
```

and i have this line in GameScene inside my didbegin contact , when the user interacts with a  coin

```
Variables.CoinsCollected += 1
```

and i have this line that updates the labelnode for the coins variable

```
coinsCollectedLabel = SKLabelNode(text: "coins: \(Variables.CoinsCollected)")
```

and everything works fine except that it doesn't get saved and i know i am missing something and i tried reading a lot of people's problem with the same issue but it didn't work, so if any of you guys could help me i would be highly appreciate it

Comment: You have code for *saving* your `CoinsCollected` but do you have code to *load it* from `UserDefaults`?

Comment: @danorm i edited my question and i have this line but i am not sure if that's what you are talking about

Comment: Check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40330947/1689376

Comment: The way you read your coins from UserDefaults:

    let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
    if let coinsCollected = defaults.stringForKey("CoinsCollected") {
        Variables.CoinsCollected = coinsCollected
    }

The value you get is an optional, so you need to check if the value is actually set.

Comment: You may already know this, but NSUserDefaults doesn't track any future updates you make. If you make another change you have to save it again. It might be worth it to write a [didSet](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Properties.html) for CoinsCollected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in your `Variables` class so your coins are always saved in a persistent file:

```
class Variables {

    static let userDefaults = UserDefaults.standard

    struct Constants {
        static let CoinsCollectedKey = "CoinsCollected"
    }

    static var CoinsCollected: Int {
        get {
            return userDefaults.integer(forKey: self.Constants.CoinsCollectedKey)
        }

        set(value) {
            userDefaults.setValue(value, forKey: self.Constants.CoinsCollectedKey)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help !!

Answer (score 1):

```
let defaults = UserDefaults.standard

...
//after Initializing Variables Instance

//get saved value
guard Variables.CoinsCollected = defaults.integer(forKey: "CoinsCollected") else {
    print("Previously saved coins don't exist")

    //create UserDefaults value for coins
    defaults.set(Variables.CoinsCollected, forKey: "CoinsCollected")
}
```

I think it would be worth saving your entire Variables object instead, so that you can get any new values you add to your `struct` later - in which case you should serialize your `Variables` object using (for example)

```
//set object
defaults.set(Variables, forKey: "Variables")
//read object
let variables: Variables = defaults.object(forKey: "Variables")

//theoretically you should now be able to get CoinsCollected value within your retrieved object~
//e.g.
print(variables.CoinsCollected)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help !!

Comment: no problem~ I think @marosoaie 's answer is better and more clever than mine. Good luck!